How can illusionists about phenomenology think consciousness is explainable through science when science seemingly inquires into phenomonology?
I think I understand that the SEP has Dennett denying the existence of qualia (1) as phenomenal character. "According to illusionists (Dennett 2019, 2020; Frankish 2016; Kammerer 2021), conscious experience is an illusion. It certainly seems to us that conscious experiences, and thus qualia (at least in sense (1) of the four senses distinguished at the beginning of this entry) exist, but in reality there are no such things."
The following paragraph seems to suggests Dennett, an illusionist, leans on science to explain consciousness:
"One's view of the prospects for explaining consciousness will typically depend upon one's perspective. Optimistic physicalists will likely see current explanatory lapses as merely the reflection of the early stage of inquiry and sure to be remedied in the not too distant future (Dennett 1991, Searle 1992, P. M.Churchland 1995)"
Let's say I understand one can deny phenomenological experiences. Okay. But aren't phenomenological experiences in the purview of science? So how can Dennett and similar philosophers have it both ways, lean on science but claim phenomenological aspects aren't real (since science does seem to study phenomenological aspects)?
I get that if you deny phenomenological experiences you don't seek to explain them. BUT, how can one then lean on science to explain consciousness when there is science attacking the "what it's like" question?  Aren't most therapists doing some kind of phenomenological inquiry? E.g. they don't just ask what happened, but how did what happened make you feel. Or doctors asking how your pain level is in addition to what happened.

Illusionists deny phenomenal character of experiences as conventionally conceptualized (which supports the idea of physically irreducible qualia, "what it is like") , they do not deny that something called "phenomenal experiences" is there and in need of explaining. It is an error theory project. As an analogy, ethical error theorists deny that moral talk is referential, they do not deny that it is in need of explaining and proceed to explain what it is 'really' about. In the process, they rely on science (game theory, evolutionary biology) for the purpose.

@Conifold so illusionism doesn’t  depend on doctors and therapists being error theorists themselves or not?

I do not think doctors and therapists need to do much work. The thrust of error theory is that conventional talk is mostly fine for practical purposes, but needs to be polished/supplemented on fine points, often informed by advanced science. In this case, it would rely on neuroscientists laying out mechanisms behind folk psychology in ways that suggest and can explain pervasive misinterpretation of phenomenality. Carruthers in Phenomenal Consciousness and Kammerer give sketches of what such an error theory might hypothetically look like. But neuroscience may undermine illusionism instead.

Dennett's approach to studying consciousness scientifically he called Heterophenomenology.  It primarily consists of treating internal reports as 3rd person data.  First person reports can be compiled and analyzed. They also can be compared to other observations available to researchers.  Here is a Wikipedia summary:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterophenomenology
Dennett claimed heterophenomenology was just how science operates in all other circumstances too.  But as one digs into Dennett's approach, this is not actually the case.  Dennett smuggles in two explicitly behaviorist assumptions in his Heterophenomenology method that are very much not standard.
Relative to consciousness, Dennett's presumption is that these reports constitute a fictional narrative, and can be evaluated for consistency to the world around it, and internal consistency, just as a fictional story can.  But other sciences do not treat reports about primary data as FICTION, nor theories about what is creating that data s fictional inventions!  Instead, unseen phenomenon, IF they make highly successful predictions for us, are treated as real.    This is the core principle of indirect realism, and gives us quarks, Higg's bosons, entropy, ecological niches, species, British Constitution, a Symphony etc. Unlike Dennett, most of us treat selfhood, agency, qualia, thoughts, purposes, and other minds as real as well, extending indirect realism to the mental world, just as we do to the abstract world of theoretical physics and the emergent phenomena of life sciences.
Additionally, Dennett holds that one can treat the reports about conscious experiences as identical to and equivalent to that experience.  IE the "behavior" of a report is the only data he admits exists, while the first person experiencer knows that words have far narrower band width than experience do, so the "report" is always an incomplete summary of the actual first person data, as all the rest of us know.
Treating either or both first and 3rd person data as data, of course allows for a scientific study of consciousness.  So Dennett's 3rd person only approach is also science, although a science hampered by significant data loss.  I don't think your interest in the question turns on this part of the answer, however.
Dennett's conclusion that consciousness is a fictional narrative -- THAT is where I believe your interest focuses.  I actually defend Dennett here in principle.  It IS legitimate to conclude that primary data is mistaken.  Sometimes we ARE wrong about what we think is happening.  Witness testimony is notoriously unreliable in criminal trials.  So -- could one do his 3rd person analysis, and infer that there is no actual "self" there in self reports?  AND have this be science?  Yes, it could.
What I object to is that Dennett makes this presumption in his methodology, with a possible bias in his analysis due to circular reinforcement, and then in a clear case of motivated reasoning, seeks to find confirmations of his model that there is no "there" there for consciousness.
Dennett's model is actually more complex than this brief discussion has accounted for.  He holds that we do significant unconscious processing, following a process he describes as a Multiple Drafts Model, and then one of those drafts takes over the nervous system and guides our actions.  THEN the brain writes that model into long term memory, backdating that memory to when the vents took place.  Dennett then proposed an identity theory relation, where our apparent conscious experience is identical to the process of writing a backdated long term memory, AND that somehow the backdating works on both sides of the identity.
My belief is that this model would better describe qualia as features of that deluded experience, rather than holding that they not exist at all. But Denett disagreed, in a move that I suspect made his model even harder to accept for most readers.
While I defend the principle behind Dennett's thinking, I disagree on the threshold that one should use to invoke declaring primary data to be invalid.  Science prioritizes data over theory.  Data is only thrown out if there is overwhelming evidence against it.  And there is not overwhelming evidence against consciousness, qualia, selfhood, and agency.

+1 "Dennett's model is actually more complex than this brief discussion has accounted for." Yeah, I think Consciousness Explained is like a 600 page book! :D

Consciousness Explained is not well structured to understand what Dennett is saying.   At one point in CE he admits to deliberately writing so he is not quotable as a summary, as he fears his views would be rejected based on such a summary.  At another point, he admits that CE is primarily intuition pumps, and he wrote it with the goal of replacing his reader's internal operating systems so we would non-rationally no longer even think we are conscious.  I. E. he tried to brainwash us, rather than convince us, following Julian Jayne's memetic operating system replacement theory.

@JD  To understand Dennett's theory, and the reasons he holds by it, I recommend instead Susan Blackmore's A Very Short Introduction to Consciousness.  She summarizes and justifies Dennett's model, and she is a very clear writer, and kept herself to ~120 pages.  Here is a review:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1C1TJFIWBZ8ZQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0198794738

It's not just that "phenomenological experience" is under the purview of science. Science itself is one large "phenomenological experience".
So if you deny phenomenological experiences, you deny any ground to science itself. This is why Dennet and co. are self-contradicting.
People keep confusing themselves with unwitting distinctions between first-person and third-person narratives, but in truth, there is no such thing as a third-person narrative. Every narrative has an author. If you say: "Bob takes the subway every morning," you mean something like: "I think Bob takes the subway every morning".
